# Multiple many-to-many filter with range using filteriffic

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I should say that the code I have works. I feel like there has to be a much more efficient way to do it (especially when I just crashed my server with it).

Relevant schema:

```
  create_table "item_total_stats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "item_stat_type_id"
    t.integer  "stat_amount"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  end
  create_table "item_stat_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "display_text"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "display_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
```

Relevant models:

```
class ItemStatType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_stats
    has_many :item_total_stats
end
class ItemTotalStat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :item_stat_type
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_total_stats
end
```

Overview:

There are approximately 30 different `ItemStatType`s. I am trying to setup a filter with boxes to allow users to enter a minimum and a maximum for each one. At the moment, all ~30 `ItemStatType`s are hard coded as a scope in the `Item` model.

An example of the 2 scopes for each `ItemStatType`:

```
  scope :saim_g, lambda{ |reference_value|
    found_stats = [ItemStatType.where(name: "Aim").first.id]
    # get a reference to the join table
    total_stats = ItemTotalStat.arel_table
    # get a reference to the filtered table
    items = Item.arel_table
    # let AREL generate a complex SQL query
    puts reference_value
    where(
      ItemTotalStat \
        .where(total_stats[:item_id].eq(items[:id])) \
        .where(total_stats[:item_stat_type_id].in([*found_stats].map(&:to_i))) \
        .where("stat_amount >= ?", reference_value) \
        #.where(total_stats[:stat_amount].eq(reference_value)) \
        .exists
    )
  }
  scope :saim_l, lambda{ |reference_value|
    found_stats = [ItemStatType.where(name: "Aim").first.id]
    # get a reference to the join table
    total_stats = ItemTotalStat.arel_table
    # get a reference to the filtered table
    items = Item.arel_table
    # let AREL generate a complex SQL query
    puts reference_value
    where(
      ItemTotalStat \
        .where(total_stats[:item_id].eq(items[:id])) \
        .where(total_stats[:item_stat_type_id].in([*found_stats].map(&:to_i))) \
        .where("stat_amount <= ?", reference_value) \
        #.where(total_stats[:stat_amount].eq(reference_value)) \
        .exists
    )
  }
```

I am creating the view like this:

```
<% ItemStatType.order('name asc').each do |stat_type| %>
    <div class="swtor-ui" style="float: left;position: relative; width: 250px;">
        <%= stat_type.name %><%= render_filterrific_spinner %><br>
        <% begin %>
            <% greater_then_string = "s#{stat_type.name.downcase}_g" %>
            <% less_then_string = "s#{stat_type.name.downcase}_l" %>
            <%= f.text_field(
                greater_then_string.parameterize.underscore.to_sym,
                placeholder: "minumum",
                class: "filterrific-periodically-observed"
            ) %>
            --
            <%= f.text_field(
                less_then_string.parameterize.underscore.to_sym,
                placeholder: "maximum",
                class: "filterrific-periodically-observed"
            ) %>
        <% rescue %>
            Unknown error occured
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Basically, I am trying to figure out a better way to go about this. Since it can run through the scopes multiple times it takes a good amount of processing power (and crashed my server while it was hidden behind a beta tag and only about 3 people had access to it).

When I was originally trying to build this, I was hoping to originally find a way to have this all happen in one scope. But without hard coding (which I ended up doing anyways) each `ItemStatType`, I could not find a way to do that with having the form the way I want it to look.

Comment: screenshots of the UI might make it easier to understand what this code does.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the relevant portion.  http://imgur.com/89nCF1v